# Frozen-Flask errors while running cProfile

Tags: python, flask, cprofile, flask-frozen

Building my static site (which uses Flask-Frozen to freeze a Flask app) works fine, but when I tried to profile it with `python -m cProfile athena.py`, I get the error

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/build

ie Frozen-Flask is trying to create its build folder in python's home folder on my system, not my current working directory. (Even though I am using a venv! `which python` yields `/path/to/dir/bin/python`.)

I was able to circumvent this by instantiating my Flask app with a hardcoded root path:

```
athena = Flask(__name__, root_path='/path/to/dir')
```

But then I get this error:

> MissingURLGeneratorWarning: Nothing frozen for endpoints page,
> hardpagelink. Did you forget a URL generator?

Trying to narrow down the issue with a debugger, I see that `pages` yields an empty list while profiling, and a list of pages in regular mode, which makes me suspect that the index is not being generated, or is generated somewhere else.

In addition there are some differences in my `config` (which is just generated from `__name__`):

> Profiling config: 'DEBUG': False, 'FLATPAGES_AUTO_RELOAD': 'if debug',
> 'FLATPAGES_EXTENSION': '.html'
>
> Regular config: 'DEBUG': True,
> 'FLATPAGES_AUTO_RELOAD': True,       'FLATPAGES_EXTENSION': '.md',
> 'FREEZER_BASE_URL': 'http://localhost/', 'FREEZER_REMOVE_EXTRA_FILES':
> False

Here is the gist of my code (full code is [here](https://github.com/lordgrenville/athena/blob/master/athena.py)):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_flatpages import FlatPages
from flask_frozen import Freezer
from flask_static_compress import FlaskStaticCompress

DEBUG = True
FLATPAGES_AUTO_RELOAD = DEBUG
FLATPAGES_EXTENSION = ".md"
FREEZER_REMOVE_EXTRA_FILES = False
FREEZER_BASE_URL = "http://localhost/"

athena = Flask(__name__)
athena.config.from_object(__name__)
pages = FlatPages(athena)
freezer = Freezer(athena)

@athena.route("/")
def index():
    posts = [page for page in pages if "ispage" not in page.meta]
    hpages = [page for page in pages if "ispage" in page.meta]
    return render_template(
        "index.html", pages=posts, hpages=hpages)


@athena.route("/<path:path>/")
def hardpagelink(path):
    hpage = ""
    for page in pages:
        if page.path == path:
            if page.meta["ispage"]:
                hpage = page
    hpages = [page for page in pages if "ispage" in page.meta]
    return render_template("hard.html", page=hpage, hpages=hpages)


@athena.route("/posts/<path:path>/")
def page(path):
    page = pages.get_or_404(path)
    hpages = [page for page in pages if "ispage" in page.meta]
    return render_template("page.html", page=page, hpages=hpages)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    freezer.freeze()
```

If anyone wants to reproduce this here are instructions for setting up an env:

```
git clone https://github.com/lordgrenville/athena.git
cd athena/
brew install jez/formulae/pandoc-sidenote
# or cabal install pandoc-sidenote
npm install -g less
python3 -m venv blogenv/ && source blogenv/bin/activate
pip install werkzeug pypandoc virtualenv flask-flatpages frozen-flask pandoc-crossref flask-static-compress feedgen
python athena.py build
python -m cProfile athena.py build  # fails
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the FREEZER_DESTINATION parameter when creating the Freezer instance?

Comment: Hmm, so setting that (with `freezer.app.config['FREEZER_DESTINATION'] = os.getcwd()`) gets me past that error, but then I get `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html`, implying it's moving to the wrong directory at another point (since there is an `index.html` in the working dir)